# Cucumber: nested scenario outline cycles

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

Scenario to automate:

```
 Given  <precondition> was fulfilled
 And <user> is authorized
 When user requests <endpoint>
 Then user should receive <code> response
```

Test data matrix:

```
      | precondition       | endpoint          | user1 | user 2    | ....
      |                    | /users            | OK    | Not Found |
      |                    | /roles            | OK    | OK        |
      |                    | /create_user      | OK    | OK        |
      | object user exists | /update_user      | OK    | OK        |
      | object user exists | /delete_user      | OK    | OK        |
      |                    | /create_data_role | OK    | Not Found |
      | data role exists   | /update_data_role | OK    | Not Found |
  ....
```

There's around 20 users with different role combination and around 20 endpoints.
Need to verify each endpoint for each user - so it should be a nested cycle.
How do I do it?

Comment: What is wrong with what you have now?

Comment: And what do you mean by "nested cycle?"

Comment: Nested because each row it's a test with it's own precondition. and then there's a cycle for each user.
The problem here that I examples table can't be parsed (only data table in the step can be manipulated, but it's used for single test and not outline - it will not do cycle for each row).  And  when using Examples table headers are constants - I can't indicate status code for this particular user

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this in Cucumber - reasons

1) You get no benefit from putting all these routes and conditions in Gherkin. Nobody can read them and make sense of them especially if you trying something combinatorial

2) Cuke scenarios run slowly, and you want to run lots of them, you could dramatically reduce your run time by writing a fast unit test instead.

3) If you write this test in code you can write it much more elegantly than you can in Gherkin.

4) Dealing with errors is painful (as you've already pointed out)

You are using the wrong tool for this particular job, use something else.

Comment: This is the right answer.  The whole point of Cucumber is to capture business rules in plain language so the team can have a shared understanding of them.  Trying to use it as a test runner for integration tests is going to be nothing but a ball and chain.

My rule of thumb for scenario outlines is that they should never check for both positive and negative results.  That's a good sign that you're mashing multiple business rules into one scenario, rather than multiple examples of the same rule.  And the way this is testing multiple endpoints, it's clearly mixing business rules.

Answer (score 0):

Yet I come up with this option, but it doesn't follow gherkin convention because When and Then steps a jammed in one
 1. Preconditions moved to @Before hook
 2. Scenario

```
Given <user> is authorized
Then <user> requests functionality appropriate response code should be received
| ENDPOINT                          | USER1 | USER2|
| /users                            | 200   | 404  |
| /create_user                      | 200   | 404  | 
| /update_user                      | 200   | 404  |
Examples:
| username |
| USER1    |
| USER2    |
```

It's also inconvenient because when tests failed it takes time to identify faulty endpoint(S)